# The value given by the Excel NOW() function

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2011

I have an Excel sheet that does a some `SUMIFS()` over manually entered data, including some kind of test for entry date.

When I enter a new data line, I first type `=NOW()` in the cell then copy-paste special value it in the same place.

The weird thing that happens is, that - sometimes - the `SUMIFS` goes wrong. However, if I go back into the cell, add a space and remove that space again, it works. As if the value format is changed.

This leads to my question: What kind of value is produced by `NOW()` and how is it different from a 'normal' date+time value? (And is there an easy solution for my problem?)

**Edit. You can do this yourself.** Enter =NOW() in two cells. Copy-paste special value them both. Check if they are the same. They are. Go into one, add a space and remove it. Press enter. The check now shows false!

[image]

Edit 2. OK. That's because the value is rounded when you add a space and remove it.

[image]

However, that still leaves the question why my `sumifs` cannot deal with the original value.

Comment: could you please confirm that calculation is set to automatic? If so, please provide the sumif function. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`NOW()` returns the current date and time as a floating point number. The integer portion is the number of days that has passed after a certain date and the decimal portion is the time that has passed since midnight.

I suspect that when the `SUMIFS()` function returns the incorrect value is that it need updating since Excel did not recognize when the value of the cell changed. To do an update, move the cursor to the cell and press <kbd>F9</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks. I've added a DIY demonstration to the question. SUMIFS has nothing to do with it, it appears.

Comment: Ah. Indeed the value changes (a little)! Still, that should not be a problem for my sumifs... Aargh. (Also, updating did not work.)

Comment: Although, when this happened, I did try updating, but not while _on_ the cell. Perhaps that would work.